# Como acessar atributos de um objeto vindo de uma requisição com node

Tags: javascript, node.js

tenho uma requisição que retorna o seguinte:

```
object
{ responseHeader: 
   { status: 0,
     QTime: 0,
  response: 
   { numFound: 22,
     start: 0,
     docs: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  }
```

Gostaria de saber como posso acessar os atributos de cada objeto de cada vez, meu código até agora é o seguinte:

```
var request = require('request');
request('request link', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error);
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);

        var body = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(typeof(body));

        console.log(body);

        var stringfied = JSON.stringify(body, null, 2);
        console.log(stringfied);


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode acessar a propriedade `body.response.docs` que será um `array`. Assim você pode percorrer este `array`:

```
const { docs } = body.response;

for (const doc in docs) {
   console.log(doc);
}
```

> [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
>
> O laço for...in  interage sobre propriedades enumeradas de um objeto, na ordem original de inserção.  O laço pode ser executado para cada propriedade distinta do objeto.
>
> **Syntaxe**
>
> ```
> for (variavel in objeto) {...
> }
> ```